# Summing rows after first occurance of a certain number

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to to get the sum of the rows after first occurrence of a certain number. In this case it is `'10'` for instance.

I though If we can know the row number after first occurrence and the ending row number of that group and we can sum in between them.

I can get the first occurrence of '10' each group but I don't  know how can get the sum of the rows.

```
df <- data.frame(gr=rep(c(1,2),c(7,9)), 
                 y_value=c(c(0,0,10,8,8,6,0),c(0,0,10,10,5,4,2,0,0)))

    > df
       gr y_value
    1   1       0
    2   1       0
    3   1      10
    4   1       8
    5   1       8
    6   1       6
    7   1       0
    8   2       0
    9   2       0
    10  2      10
    11  2      10
    12  2       5
    13  2       4
    14  2       2
    15  2       0
    16  2       0
```

My initial attempt is below which is not working for some reason even for grouping part:(!

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%
  mutate(check1=any(y_value==10),row_sum=which(y_value == 10)[1])
```

Expected output

```
> df
           gr y_value sum_rows_range
        1   1       0      22/4
        2   1       0      22/4  
        3   1      10      22/4
        4   1       8      22/4
        5   1       8      22/4
        6   1       6      22/4
        7   1       0      22/4
        8   2       0      21/6
        9   2       0      21/6
        10  2      10      21/6
        11  2      10      21/6
        12  2       5      21/6
        13  2       4      21/6 
        14  2       2      21/6
        15  2       0      21/6
        16  2       0      21/6
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Why you start counting after row 11, but not 10 in gr 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  slice(if(any(y_value == 10)) (which.max(y_value == 10)+1):n() else row_number()) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(y_value),
            rows = n()) %>%
  inner_join(df)
```

**Notes:**

The main idea is to `slice` on the rows after the first 10 occurs. `any(y_value == 10))` and `else row_number()` are just to take care of the case where there are no 10's in `y_value`.

Reading the documentation for `?which.max`, you will notice that when it is applied to a logical vector, in this case `y_value == 10`, "with both `FALSE` and `TRUE` values, `which.min(x)` and `which.max(x)` return the index of the first `FALSE` or `TRUE`, respectively, as `FALSE < TRUE`."

In other words, `which.max(y_value == 10)` will give the index of the first occurrence of 10. By adding 1 to it, I can start `slice`ing from the value right after the first occurrence of 10.

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 16 × 4
      gr   sum  rows y_value
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
1      1    22     4       0
2      1    22     4       0
3      1    22     4      10
4      1    22     4       8
5      1    22     4       8
6      1    22     4       6
7      1    22     4       0
8      2    21     6       0
9      2    21     6       0
10     2    21     6      10
11     2    21     6      10
12     2    21     6       5
13     2    21     6       4
14     2    21     6       2
15     2    21     6       0
16     2    21     6       0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is that possible we ca still keep the original y_values column ?

Comment: @Alexander Edited my answer. Just needed to add an `inner_join` with the original `df`

Comment: could you little bit explain about the part `(which.max(y_value == 10)+1):n() else row_number()` ? I could not get it:)

Comment: @Alexander Added more explanation. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit convoluted, and I'm not positive it's what you're looking for, but it does match your output.

```
  df %>% 
    group_by(gr) %>% 
    mutate(is_ten = cumsum(y_value == 10)) %>% 
    filter(is_ten > 0) %>% 
    filter(!(y_value == 10 & is_ten == 1)) %>% 
    group_by(gr) %>% 
    summarize(sum_rows_range = paste(sum(y_value), n(), sep = "/")) %>% 
    right_join(df)

# A tibble: 16 x 3
      gr sum_rows_range y_value
   <dbl>          <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1           22/4       0
 2     1           22/4       0
 3     1           22/4      10
 4     1           22/4       8
 5     1           22/4       8
 6     1           22/4       6
 7     1           22/4       0
 8     2           21/6       0
 9     2           21/6       0
10     2           21/6      10
11     2           21/6      10
12     2           21/6       5
13     2           21/6       4
14     2           21/6       2
15     2           21/6       0
16     2           21/6       0
```