# Summing rows based on conditional in groups

Tags: r, dplyr

Previously I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374470/summing-rows-after-first-occurance-of-a-certain-number) related to this question but I need more elegant and general way to solve this.
I have data separated in groups and I want to sum some rows in range based on conditional. I prefer to use 'dplyr' to do this because it's more straight forward for me to understand.

The conditionals which I need as follows;

1: for group 1 ;
find the first occurrence of '10' and sum the rows **after** this occurrence to the end of the group and count how many rows.

2: for group 2;'find the last occurrence of '10' and and sum the rows **before** this occurrence to the beginning of the group and count how many rows!

3: for group 3; find the first occurrence of '10' and and sum the rows **before** this occurrence to the starting row of the group and count how many rows.

```
df <- data.frame(gr=rep(c(1,2,3),c(7,9,11)), 
                 y_value=c(c(0,0,10,8,8,6,0),c(10,10,10,8,7,6,2,0,0), c(8,5,8,7,6,2,10,10,8,7,0)))


> df
   gr y_value
1   1       0
2   1       0
3   1      10
4   1       8
5   1       8
6   1       6
7   1       0
8   2      10
9   2      10
10  2      10
11  2       8
12  2       7
13  2       6
14  2       2
15  2       0
16  2       0
17  3       8
18  3       5
19  3       8
20  3       7
21  3       6
22  3       2
23  3      10
24  3      10
25  3       8
26  3       7
27  3       0
```

It guess something like this should work but cannot figured out how to implement this to `dplyr`

```
count <- function(y,gr){
    if (any(y==10)&(gr==1)) {
     *
     *
     *
if (any(y==10)&(gr==2)) 
 *
 *
 *
 *
```

}
}

```
df%>%
library(dplyr)

  df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  do(data.frame(.,count_rows=count(y_value,gr)))
```

expected output

```
  > df
    gr y_value sum nrow
1   1       0  22   4
2   1       0  22   4
3   1      10  22   4
4   1       8  22   4
5   1       8  22   4
6   1       6  22   4
7   1       0  22   4
8   2      10  23   6
9   2      10  23   6
10  2      10  23   6
11  2       8  23   6
12  2       7  23   6
13  2       6  23   6
14  2       2  23   6
15  2       0  23   6
16  2       0  23   6
17  3       8  28   6
18  3       5  28   6
19  3       7  28   6
20  3       6  28   6
21  3       2  28   6
22  3      10  28   6
23  3      10  28   6
24  3       8  28   6
25  3       7  28   6
26  3       0  28   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps!
(**Edit note:** modified code after OP updated his original requirement)

```
#sample data - I slightly changed sample data (replaced 0 by 10 in 2nd row) for group 1 to satisfy your condition
df <- data.frame(gr=rep(c(1,2,3),c(7,9,11)), 
                 y_value=c(c(0,10,10,8,8,6,0),c(10,10,10,8,7,6,2,0,0), c(8,5,8,7,6,2,10,10,8,7,0)))

library(dplyr)
df_temp <- df %>% 
  group_by(gr) %>% 
  mutate(rows_to_aggregate=cumsum(y_value==10)) %>% 
  filter(ifelse(gr==1, rows_to_aggregate !=0, ifelse(gr==2, rows_to_aggregate ==0 | y_value==10, rows_to_aggregate ==0))) %>% 
  filter(ifelse(gr==1, row_number(gr) != 1, ifelse(gr==2, row_number(gr) != n(), rows_to_aggregate ==0))) %>% 
  mutate(nrow=n(), sum=sum(y_value)) %>%
  select(gr,sum,nrow) %>%
  distinct()

#final output
df<- left_join(df,df_temp, by='gr')
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Actually I just realized that I made a mistake about 'group2' part. It should be changed to 'find the last occurrence of '10' and and sum the rows before this occurrence to the beginning of the group and count how many rows!. In that case the solution should be modified I suppose. Sorry!

Comment: @Alexander Glad that it helped! Please refer the modified answer as per your updated requirement.

Comment: Thanks  for updating the solution. I hope it would be helpful for also other users. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after `cummax`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(in_scope = if_else(gr == 1,
                            cummax(lag(y_value == 10, default = FALSE)),
                            if_else(gr == 2,
                                    cummax(lag(y_value == 10, default = FALSE) & y_value != 10),
                                    1L - cummax(y_value == 10)))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  summarise(the_sum = sum(y_value * in_scope),
            the_count = sum(in_scope))


# A tibble: 3 x 3
     gr the_sum the_count
  <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>
1     1      22         4
2     2      23         6
3     3      36         6
```