# Filtering and summing rows in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data that I want to first filter some rows and sum those remaining rows.

The filtering conditions as follows;

1. for gr==1 find the last occurrence of `y_value==10` and keep the all rows before it (including the last occurrence of this value 10 row)!
2. for gr==2 find the first occurrence of `y_value==10` and keep all the rows after it (including the first occurrence of this value 10 row)!

The data is like this;

```
df <- data.frame(gr=rep(c(1,2),c(8,7)), 
                 y_value=c(c(2,10,10,8,10,6,0,0),c(0,0,10,10,6,8,10)))



    gr y_value
1   1       2
2   1      10
3   1      10
4   1       8
5   1      10
6   1       6
7   1       0
8   1       0
9   2       0
10  2       0
11  2      10
12  2      10
13  2       6
14  2       8
15  2      10
```

I tried this in the light of [summing-rows-based-on-conditional-in-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387680/summing-rows-based-on-conditional-in-groups);

```
df_temp <- df %>% 
  group_by(gr) %>% 
  mutate(rows_to_aggregate=cumsum(y_value==10)) %>% 
  filter(ifelse(gr==1, rows_to_aggregate !=0, ifelse(gr==2, rows_to_aggregate ==0 | y_value==10, rows_to_aggregate ==0))) %>% 
  filter(ifelse(gr==1, row_number(gr) != 1, ifelse(gr==2, row_number(gr) != n(), rows_to_aggregate ==0)))
```

but the if I do `rows_to_aggregate !=0` in `gr==1` the rows in the interest will be gone! Any guide at this point will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df_to_aggregate <- df %>% 
    group_by(gr) %>% 
    mutate(rows_to_aggregate = cumsum(y_value == 10)) %>% 
    filter(!(gr == 1 & rows_to_aggregate == max(rows_to_aggregate) & y_value != 10)) %>%
    filter(!(gr == 2 & rows_to_aggregate == 0)) %>%
    select(-rows_to_aggregate)
df_to_aggregate

# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   gr [2]
     gr y_value
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       2
2     1      10
3     1      10
4     1       8
5     1      10
6     2      10
7     2      10
8     2       6
9     2       8
10    2      10
```

Comment: Thanks for the clever answer, OTH I want to keep the `10` after the `8` in `gr==1`. That's the main bottleneck:(( I also updated the OP. Sorry about that I should mentioned that!

Comment: @Alexander I see. Changing the filter conditions a little bit should do. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your algorithm is great!

Answer (score 2):

Do not know how to do it in dplyr, but this code seems to work

```
gr1 = df[df$gr==1,]
last = tail(which(gr1$y_value==10),1)
gr1 = gr1[1:(last-1),]
gr2 = df[df$gr==2,]
first = head(which(gr2$y_value==10),1)
gr2 = gr2[(first+1):dim(gr2)[1],]
final = rbind(gr1,gr2)
```

Comment: Thanks. wish to have solution in dplyr if possible;)

Answer (score 1):

You can `slice` with a different slicing condition for each `gr`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(gr) %>% 
  slice(if(any(gr==1)) {1:max(which(y_value==10))} else {min(which(y_value==10)):n()})
```

> ```
>       gr y_value
>  1     1       2
>  2     1      10
>  3     1      10
>  4     1       8
>  5     1      10
>  6     2      10
>  7     2      10
>  8     2       6
>  9     2       8
> 10     2      10
> ```